# Is it possible to display the same banner ad throughout an app in Android?

Tags: android

Is there a way to display the same banner ad throughout my Android application using different activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost impossible, bro!

Your banner is controller by Ads Providers. Unless they provide customizing to configure ads like you said. As all providers I knew, there's none support that.